# How to validate textbox to enter only numerical or one string value that is 'AB'

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to validate textbox to enter only numerical or one string value that is 'AB'
means the in that textbox you can enter either numerical or 'AB'

so.. how to do

Comment: *Regular expressions*? Something like `^(AB)|([0-9]+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the commented suggestion for RegEx, you can use `TryParse()` method like

```
 int number;
 if(Int32.TryParse(txt1.Text, out number) || txt1.Text == "AB")
 //Your code here
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion it works for me